# this.requiresConfig for multitasks in Grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I have a config for a multitask "deploy":

```
deploy: {
  options: {
    server: default.com
  }
  prod: {
  }
  test: {
    options: {
      server: test.com
    }
  }
}
```

There are two places where the target might get its server from. In the corresponding multi-task I wanna check the server option is set (and I don't care where it is set).

It seems that this.requiresConfig can only check for

```
this.requiresConfig('deploy.options.server')
```

or

```
this.requiresConfig('deploy.target.options.server')
```

but not make a check that checks that the option is set either globally or locally.

How can I work around this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

`this.options()` could get both globally and locally options for this target. So you may try to check config from this object.